# switch in php have a 'selected' in syntax?

Tags: php

Im studying php and i found this example to select(list/menu)
I click in a link in a form to change the city (name or the state)  and when I click the link will take me to another form and it should appear automatically the name and state of the selected city in a textfield and the state in a select (list / menu).
And to do this in this example im seeing is using the case.
 I'm not understanding what he does in this line: 
 `'case' NY ': $ city1 =' selected '; break; "  ('selected' is part of switch loop in php?

```
 switch($commands->regist->CITY_COD)
           {
               case 'NY': $city1 = 'selected';break;
               case 'WC': $city2 = 'selected';break;
               case 'AR': $city3 = 'selected';break;            
           }
           ?>
            <option value="NY" <?php echo $city1; ?>>NY</option>
            <option value="WC" <?php echo $city2; ?>>WC</option>
            <option value="AR" <?php echo $city3; ?>>AR</option>

        </select></td>
```

im not understanding how this works fine, someone can help?

Comment: Not knocking you for wanting to understand this, but be aware that this is really not an example you want to model your own code after.

Comment: A `switch` is basically another form of an IF-statement. So this `case 'NY': $city1 = 'selected';break;` could also be written as `if($commands->regist->CITY_COD == 'NY'){ $city1 = 'selected'}`. The `break` command ensures that the code isn't evaluated further if the case returns true. Look at grossvogel's example, it shows the anatomy of the switch-statement in a more readable way.

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to the following:

```
if ($commands->regist->CITY_COD == 'NY'){
    $city1 = 'selected';
} elseif($commands->regist->CITY_COD == 'WC') {
    $city2 = 'selected';
} elseif($commands->regist->CITY_COD == 'AR'){
    $city3 = 'selected';
}
```

It assigns "selected" to one of the variables and then inserts it into the HTML

Comment: thank you very much, but i still dont understanding how this work. i understand the case but dont know how this will work, specially in this line <option value="NY" <?php echo $city1; ?>>NY</option>, it will write selected in NY option but i dont know how with this can appear the state automatic when we click in link to the change form!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `switch` is like so:

```
switch ($input) {
  case 'option one':
    // some code to run if $input == 'option one';
    break;
  case 'option two':
    // some code to run if $input == 'option two';
    break;
  default:
    // some code to run if no other case matched
    break;
}
```

In your example, it sets `$city1` equal to the string `'selected'` if `$commands->regist->CITY_COD` is equal to `'NY'`. Likewise, if `$commands->regist->CITY_COD` is equal to `'WC'` then `$city2` will be set to the string `'selected'`.

There's no variable initialization here, but it looks like all three of the city variables will be empty if they're not set in the switch. So, if `$commands->regist->CITY_COD` is equal to `'NY'`, then `$city1` will be set to `'selected'` and `$city2` and `$city3` will be empty. In that case, the HTML echoed will be:

```
<option value="NY" selected>NY</option>
<option value="WC" >WC</option>
<option value="AR" >AR</option>
```

Comment: thannks for the help but i still dont understanding how this work. i understand the case but dont know how this will work, specially in this line <option value="NY" <?php echo $city1; ?>>NY</option>

Comment: It's important to understand the context switching between PHP and HTML. Each `<option>` tag is the HTML code to create an item in the pull-down list. `<?php echo $city1; ?>` switches the context over to PHP and spits the content of the `$city1` variable into the HTML. So it injects the string `'selected'` into the `<option>` tag, which makes that option pre-selected in the pull-down.

Answer (score 0):

`selected` is a property of tag `option` to tell browser to pre-select that option when loading the page. That's HTML.

Is that what you asked?

Comment: ah so maybe the problem is im studying php without studying html, i didnt know that the selected is a option of html!